# PyGame Conway's Game of Life, redraw sprites

Tags: python, pygame

When I update my array of which image the program should use for each location, I can place alive cells over dead, but the original doesn't go away and I can't add dead cells over live ones. Does anyone have a fix?

Original File

```
import pygame, pygamehandle, standard, sys
from pygame.locals import *
loader = pygamehandle.load()

pygame.mixer.music.load('music1.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

SCREEN_SIZE = (600, 400)
fps = 24
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
imgs = ["live.png", "dead.png", "background.png"]
icon = "icon.png"

screen = loader.loadScreen(SCREEN_SIZE, "Game of Life", icon)

lImgs = loader.listImgLoad(imgs)

objects, grid = loader.grid(SCREEN_SIZE, lImgs[1])

loader.blit(objects, grid)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    mouseClicked = False
    fpsClock.tick(fps)

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if i.button == 1:
                mouseposx, mouseposy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mouseposx = (mouseposx // 20) * 20
                mouseposy = (mouseposy // 20) * 20
                mousepos = (mouseposx, mouseposy)
                index = grid.index(mousepos)
                objects[index] = lImgs[0]

            if i.button == 2:
                mouseposx, mouseposy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mouseposx = (mouseposx // 20) * 20
                mouseposy = (mouseposy // 20) * 20
                mousepos = (mouseposx, mouseposy)
                index = grid.index(mousepos)
                objects[index] = lImgs[1]


        if i.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.Surface.fill(screen, [0, 0, 0])
    loader.blit(objects, grid)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I also used these functions from the pygamehandle file.

```
import pygame, standard

class load(object):

    pygame.init()

    def loadScreen(self, size, text, icon):

        pygame.display.set_caption(text, icon)
        pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load(icon))

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

        self.screen = screen

        return screen

    def listImgLoad(self, list):

        img = []

        for i in range (0, len(list)):
            img.append(pygame.image.load(list[i]).convert())

        return img

    def blit(self, items, locations):

        for i in range (0, len(items)):
            self.screen.blit(items[i], locations[i])

    def grid(self, size, object):

        objects =[]
        locations = []

        x, y = size

        for xT in range (0, int(x / 20)):
            for yT in range(0, int(y / 20)):
                objects.append(object)
                locations.append((xT * 20, yT * 20))

        return objects, locations
```

Comment: Sorry if the code is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is make a Sprite class for each cell, add a bool to deteermine if the cell is dead or alive and blit accordingly.

If you are familiar with Sprites here is [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), It may be confusing at first but they will help in making more complex games, also here is a link to my version of [The Game of Life](https://github.com/C-Dubb/Pygame-Examples/tree/master/Game%20Of%20Life)

Goodluck

Comment: Thanks. Your version was pretty useful. I will comment a link to the finished one when I complete it.